# 1st li item (tile) not aligned properly

Tags: html, css

I'm having some trouble aligning my li elements. Everything aligns nicely but the 1st element does not align properly. Also, there are weird black dots around the 1st row (which wasn't there before I added ul tag).
How do I align the first li properly?
Code for the problematic (first) li:

```
<li>
     <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="tile blue" id="tile1">
        <div align="center">
        <h3 class="title">Network Security</h3>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="row">
        <div align="center">    
        <a href="#" class="icon-white"> <i class="fa icon-white fa-users fa-lg "> </i> 10 </a>
        </div>  
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="row">
        <div class="text-center">
                                <div class="btn-toolbar" id="btns">
                                <button class="btn btn-default btn-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench"></span> Manage</button>
                                <button class="btn btn-default btn-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span> Preview</button>
                                <button class="btn btn-default btn-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> Edit Info</button>

                                </div>
                                </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
    </li>
```

Check out this fiddle I created for visualization of the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/AE3VV/1/

**UPDATE**
The bullets were causing the problem. Due to that, the 1st tile was not aligned with the tile on its right. Removing the dot solved the problem  [ li{list-style:none;}  ]

Comment: Looks fine here in Chrome.

Comment: What's the actual problem? What's the expected result and what are you seeing?

Comment: @j08691 Updated the fiddle, check it out now

Comment: Still not seeing the issue with the first item. The dot is just the default list item dot, it can be taken out easily

Comment: @Huangism the bullets were causing the problem. Due to that, the 1st tile was not aligned with the tile on its right. Removing the dot solved the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first tile looks good to me, but to remove the dots use:

```
.list-group { list-style:none; }
```